# Perimeter of a circumscribed trapezoid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

"Find the perimeter of the trapezoid:"

[image]

I know that if a trapezium is circumscribed, then it should satisfy Pitot theorem, but nothing else.

Also, found the height and length of one side, with the $30,60,90$º triangle that is created with the height of the trapezoid and that side.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only wanted a hint, I drew a more detailed picture for you.v

BTW. A $53^\circ$-$37^\circ$-$90^\circ$ right triangle, is a $3$-$4$-$5$ right triangle with the angles rounded off to the nearest degree.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is the distance from the $30°$ vertex to the tangency points nearest to it, then $x=2/\tan15°$. Similar formulas hold for the other vertices.

Comment: and for the sides that i don't know the angle?

Comment: @RodrigoPizarro You should know the angles. Utilize the fact that two lines are parallel...

Comment: Thanks, Sorry...